# Getting Text property of hyperlink clicked in list view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The list of items (hyperlinks) is shown in a listview retrieved by a query. And on clicking, it redirects to another page where i need to fetch the data of that item by using its name, which is the text that item(hyperlink). How do i access the text property (name) of the item that was clicked on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed clicking a *hyperlink* which *redirects* to another page, you cannot get that information.

The only way to do it would be to include the information you need in a querystring, and parse the querystring on the next page.

However, if you are *posting* the form to another page, and your hyperlink is actually an input, your information will be available in the post data.

If your hyperlink is actually a *server control*, there are many possibilities.

It might help to see some code.

OK, if this is your code:

```
<td> 
    <asp:Hyperlink ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl="~/anotherpage.aspx"/> 
</td>
```

There are a few things you can do. First, you can change your `asp:Hyperlink` to an `asp:LinkButton` add a click event and remove the `NavigateUrl` property:

```
<td> 
    <asp:LinkButton ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' OnClick="NameLabel_Click"/> 
</td>
```

Now, use the event handler to do what you need:

```
    //Use querystring
    protected void NameLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var link = sender as LinkButton;
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("anotherpage.aspx?name={0}", link.Text));
    }

    //Use session
    protected void NameLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var link = sender as LinkButton;
        Session["name"] = link.Text;
        Response.Redirect("anotherpage.aspx?");
    }
```

Then, in the `Page_Load` event of your landing page, you can do this:

```
//Session
var name = Session["name"];

//Querystring
var name = Request.QueryString["name"];
```

Comment: what code do you want to see? so far i haven't written the code of this task since i don't have the text, i can show you the one that retrieves the data in the listview, through a SqlDataSource. And i explicitly converted the label property of items in it to hyperlinks. Like this
<td>
<asp:Hyperlink ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl="~/anotherpage.aspx"/>
</td>

Comment: And yes i need to parse the information to the next page, but how exactly do i get that information since its the text of that hyperlink?

Comment: Try something like <asp:Hyperlink ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/anotherpage.aspx/?itemName={0}", Eval("Name").ToString()) %>'/>